# Why does std::ranges::set_difference require std::mergeable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The [`std::ranges::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/set_difference) algorithm requires the `std::mergeable` concept, which among other things, specifies that the elements of both ranges have to be copyable into the result. However, the set difference algorithm *never* copies the elements of the second range!

Is there a reason for this decision, or is it simply to make all the `set_*` algorithms have the same requirements?

Motivation: Without this requirement, we could run something like the following to filter out several map keys (note, using a projection on the map elements):

```
std::map<char, int> m{ {'a', 1}, {'b', 0}, {'u', 7} };
std::set s{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };
std::vector<std::tuple<char, int>> result;

std::ranges::set_difference(m, s, std::back_inserter(result),
    {}, [](const auto& p) { return p.first; });
```

(And indeed, if I take the “possible implementation” from cppreference.com and erase the `requires` clause to make `my_set_difference`, this code with `my_set_difference` does work fine.)

Comment: This is [LWG3534](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3534) and is tracked in [#1021](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1021).

Comment: By the way, you can get rid of projections: `m | std::views::keys`

Comment: @Red.Wave Not really. Projections only apply before comparison, but the resulting object is still filled with the original (non-projected) values. Using `views::keys` doesn't solve the original task.

Comment: I am not addressing the original question. It's clear and valid. Looks like a defect in std, and the very 1st comment has clearly addressed the issue. I'm just pointing that same functionality can be achieved through less effort.

Comment: And they are pointing out that the functionality would not actually be the same